# How can I add jQuery UI button widget to my radio_button_tag?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, radio-button

I'm brand new to javascript and am having trouble finding a way to include the jQuery UI into my app. I currently have a form containing some radio buttons to let me filter venue records displayed on the index page by type. I would like to include the jQuery button widget to give the look of tabs. I have the demo setup from the jQuery site working on my app but its only there for looks at the moment.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#radio

My current filter form:

```
  <form class="filter_form", method="get">
    <fieldset class="filter_form_fieldset">
      <legend class="filter_form_fieldset_legend">Choose a venue type:</legend>
      <% Venuetype.all.each do |v| %>
        <span class="filter_form_radio_button_label">
          <%= radio_button_tag("venuetypes[]", v.id, false)%>
          <%= v.name %>
        </span>
      <% end %>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
  </form>
```

Thanks very much for any help!

Comment: I started writing an answer when I realized that you're using `venuetypes[]` for the name of the radio buttons which seems to indicate that you're planning on sending more than one when the form is submitted? Wouldn't you want to use checkboxes rather for this purpose?

Comment: @polarblau Ahh it was originally checkboxes but I thought having radio buttons would be better suited for the kind of filters being done, I'll change the rails code, thanks for having a look.

Comment: Please see my answer below, assuming that you're using checkboxes.

Comment: And what comes to the radio buttons: If you're allowing the user to use only one filter at a time, then radio buttons make sense, but you might want to change the `name` to `venuetype`. Otherwise checkboxes would be my choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming that you're using checkboxes (see comments for original question):*

Include the necessary files into you header or footer (remember that jQuery UI needs a CSS file as well — or custom styles!) if you haven't done so yet.

Then restructure your mark-up to match something like this:

```
<fieldset class="filter_form_fieldset venuetypes">
  <legend class="filter_form_fieldset_legend">Choose a venue type:</legend>
  <% Venuetype.all.each do |v| %>
    <%= check_box_tag 'venuetypes[]', v.id, false, :id => "venuetype-#{v.id}" %>
    <label for="venuetype-<%= v.id %>"><%= v.name %></label>
  <% end %>
</fieldset>
```

Call the `buttonset` method when the DOM has been loaded e.g. in your application.js:

```
$(function() {
    $('.venuetypes').buttonset();
});
```

That should do it — here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/DZx3z/