# radio_buttons with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, radio-button

## EDIT:

**Here's the problem/question**:
Jquery buttons work (show up formatted in jquery style, as per the example in the [jquery documentation](http://jqueryui.com/button/#radio)) in the first example (venues) and don't work (don't show up formatted in jquery style) in the second (radio).

I've been trying to get jquery buttons working, but I can't seem to do it.

I've been working from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5094199/2128691) and adapted the [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DZx3z/53/)

I'm sure it must be just a small thing I'm missing - but why does this code work:

```
<fieldset class="filter_form_fieldset venues">
    <legend class="filter_form_fieldset_legend">Choose a venue type:</legend>
    <input type="checkbox" name="venuetypes[]" id="venue-1" />
    <label for="venue-1">Venue 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="venuetypes[]" id="venue-2" />
    <label for="venue-2">Venue 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="venuetypes[]" id="venue-3" />
    <label for="venue-3">Venue 3</label>
</fieldset>
```

and this code doesn't?

```
<tr>
  <td class="goal_row">goal 1: </td> 
  <td id="radio">
    <input id="score_1_1" name="score_1" type="radio" value="1" />
    <label for="score_1">1</label>
    <input id="score_1_2" name="score_1" type="radio" value="2" />
    <label for="score_1">2</label>
    <input id="score_1_3" name="score_1" type="radio" value="3" />
    <label for="score_1">3</label>
    <input id="score_1_4" name="score_1" type="radio" value="4" />
    <label for="score_1">4</label>
    <input id="score_1_5" name="score_1" type="radio" value="5" />
    <label for="score_1">5</label>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: In what way doesn't it work from the way it should, please provide more than just code

Comment: What is it that you *want it to do*? What *doesn't* it do?

Comment: apologies, updating question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DZx3z/57/)

Put the radios in a div and change the for value from name to id like this

```
<tr>


<td class="goal_row">goal 1: </td> 
  <td>
      <div id="radio">
          <input id="score_1_1" name="score_1" type="radio" value="1" />
            <label for="score_1_1">1</label>
            <input id="score_1_2" name="score_1" type="radio" value="2" />
            <label for="score_1_2">2</label>
            <input id="score_1_3" name="score_1" type="radio" value="3" />
            <label for="score_1_3">3</label>
            <input id="score_1_4" name="score_1" type="radio" value="4" />
            <label for="score_1_4">4</label>
            <input id="score_1_5" name="score_1" type="radio" value="5" />
            <label for="score_1_5">5</label>
      </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle : Need to put `radio` button `inside div` and set `div` `id` is `radio`

http://jsfiddle.net/DZx3z/61/

Answer (score -1):

ok i got it. its and id problem put this below code in your code and this will work
check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DZx3z/62/

```
<tr>
  <td class="goal_row">goal 1: </td> 
  <td>
    <div id="radio">
    <input id="score_1_1" name="score_1" type="radio" value="1" />
    <label for="score_1_1">1</label>
    <input id="score_1_2" name="score_1" type="radio" value="2" />
    <label for="score_1_2">2</label>
    <input id="score_1_3" name="score_1" type="radio" value="3" />
    <label for="score_1_3">3</label>
    <input id="score_1_4" name="score_1" type="radio" value="4" />
    <label for="score_1_4">4</label>
    <input id="score_1_5" name="score_1" type="radio" value="5" />
    <label for="score_1_5">5</label>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**what is the problem in your code:**

its a minor problem you are trying to put `name attr value` in `for attr of label` that's why is not working `for attr works for id val`